# Как «запомнить» выбраный город на сайте с городами на поддоменах?

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess, веб-программирование, seo

Как запомнить выбор города на сайте, учитывая что города реализованы в виде поддоменов.

Стоит задача сделать для сайта региональные поддомены для seo продвижения сайта в разных городах по геозависимым запросам. 
На данный момент сделал динамические уникальные для каждого поддомена роботс и сайтмап. Реализовал токены вхождений городов, чтобы для каждого города на своем поддомене выводилось упоменание релевантного города. Сделал меню выбора города.

Прописал в алиасы домена поддомен ***.domain.ru,** теперь при указывании несуществующего поддомена например **spb.domain.ru** открывается содержимое страницы **domain.ru** c упоминанием Питера, то есть всё хорошо. Так же и с остальными страницами и городами.

НО. Не знаю как реализовать запоминание выбранного города, чтобы при переходе со страницы **spb.domain.ru** на внутреннюю, например в раздел **/catalog** оставаться в пределах выбранного поддомена, т.е. чтобы в адресной строке браузера показывалось **spb.domain.ru/catalog**, а не **domain.ru/catalog**

Подскажите в каком направлении думать. Куки, .htaccess или вообще в другом. Если можно с примерами.

Comment: А у вас на сайте ссылки что ли абсолютные с `http://domain.ru/...` ? Если ссылки вида `<A HREF=/catalog>` то пользователь никогда на базовый домен не улетит

Comment: Я смотрел все топовые торговые сайты, у них наоборот убраны поддомены.

Answer (score 2):

используйте ссылки без указания схемы и домена:

```
/catalog
```

вместо

```
http://что-то/catalog
```